# Having a specific background image for each and every list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Was wondering if there was a way to condense this and have it go on

```
li:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url(1.jpg);
}
li:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url(2.jpg);
}
li:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url(3.jpg);
}
li:nth-child(4){
    background-image: url(4.jpg);
}
li:nth-child(5){
    background-image: url(5.jpg);
}
```

And so on and so on.

Would there be a way to have this go on with pure css variables or is there an easier solution with javascript?

Comment: To do it dynamically you have to do it with JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS has no way to relate, as yet, the index of the element to a property of that element's CSS; with JavaScript it's easy enough:

```
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

[].forEach.call(liElements, function (li, index) {
    li.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + index + '.jpg');
});
```

With CSS it's possible, *in future*, that the following *may* work (but this is pure speculation):

```
ul {
    counter-reset: liCount;
}

ul li {
    counter-increment: liCount;
    background-image: url(counter(liCount) '.jpg');
}
```

This does *not* work in any current browsers, and may *never* work in any browser. As noted, this is purely speculative.

Comment: Interesting idea it would be pretty need to see something like this in the future but for now the javascript option is the best. Thanks a lot appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many children you have, you'll want to use JS. Or, if you do, but don't want to type it all out, or have a max, then PHP which could just make the CSS file which would be faster than JS doing it after the load.

```
var liElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < liElems.length(); ++i){
    li.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + i + '.jpg")';
}
```

Or, for PHP:

```
for($idx = 0; $idx < MAGIC_NUM; ++$idx){
    print("li:nth-child($idx){");
    print("    background-image: url($idx.jpg);")
    print("}\n");
}
```